# Set a variable in a different class

Tags: iphone, properties, sdk

I am trying to create an application were 2 classes share a variable. Just to keep the code looking a little bit cleaner I created a 3rd class. This "third class" sole job is to house this variable.

In class 3 I put a "get" and "set" method.

SharedURL.H (Class 3)

```
@interface SharedURL : NSObject {
 NSString *theURL;
}
-(NSString *)getTheURL;
-(void)setTheURL:(NSString *)blah;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString  *theURL;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "SharedURL.h"


@implementation SharedURL

@synthesize theURL;

-(NSString *)getTheURL;
{
 return theURL;

}
-(void)setTheURL:(NSString *)blah;
{
 theURL=blah;

}
@end
```

In classes 1 and 2:
I Import the class header
I set up the instance variable like so

SharedURL *XMLURL;

I define the property like so

```
@property (readwrite, assign) SharedURL *XMLURL;
```

Then in the implementation I set the set method like this

```
[XMLURL setTheURL:@"http://localhost:8888/xml/MyXMLFile.xml"];
```

However whenever I implement the fallowing code the getter method returns nil.

NSLog(@" the url is %@", [XMLURL getTheURL]);

How can I get this to actually save the variable that I imput and then return it. I'm looking at some sample code and i cannot find my error it looks to me like I am doing it perfectly fine I think I am overlooking something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right you are calling class 3 from either class 1 or 2 (lets say 1) and set the URL then your go to class 2 and and only ask for the URL, right?

I think your problem is that you are calling something that is independent for each object. I think you can fix this by instead of saying `-(NSString *)getTheURL` and `-(void)setTheURL` you need to change it to `+(NSString *)getTheURL` and `+(void)setTheURL` (in both the .h and .m files) making it not variable dependent.

Comment: But if I set those to static classes i cannot access the instance variable i use to store the value?

Comment: Don't make it an ivar declare it before the instance and then make it `static NSString *theURL`.

Comment: I have similar problem and it's saying "Instance variable 'theURL' accessed in class method"